# How to reliably find checked boxes on an image (with cv2.findContours or another technique)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-recognition

I'm trying to identify the 6 squares on this image:

[image]

and **detect which ones are checked or black-colored** (here (1,1) and (3,2)).

- there can be some text around, or some drawing, but nothing *really* similar to checked boxes
- the image can be slightly rotated

### Approach #1

I tried with:

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for j, c in enumerate(contours):
    cv2.drawContours(imgcolor, [c], 0, COLORS[j % len(COLORS)], thickness=1)
```

but the result is rather poor:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- filter by area with `cv2.contourArea(c)`
- Use

  ```
    shape = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), closed=True)
  ```

  and keep the rectangles only with `if len(shape) == 4:` but this won't work since some of the squares are split in two or three contours: see the top right square which is recognized as a red + cyan contour
- NB: some squares are successfully recognized by a contour, but even **by two contours**, so when we `drawContour`, we see **two** contours on top of each other for the same single square

### Approach #2

Would it be possible to use the **correlation** between the original image and all the "postition-shifted + rotated + rescaled" versions of this "3x2 box pattern":

[image]

Would this allow a good detection?

### TL;DR:

**How to reliably identify the 6 boxes on such an image and find the boxes which are checked or black-colored?**

Comment: difficult problem and a bit open ended for stackoverflow.  in general you want to cut down the number of possible position/rotations you're testing against so you can get an answer in a sensible amount of time.  other issues are around the quality of the source image, are they all machine generated or will they be coming from a camera/scanner as these will introduce more artifacts for you to deal with

Comment: Yes @SamMason it comes from a scanner indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my method:

> (1) Threshold and find the external contours
>
> (2) Filter the contour by area and height/width, then distinguish by area occupy.

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: Finding the *external* contours is the key, you're right (`cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`). It's important to inverse the color before, like in your screenshot: `img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)`, after the thresholding.